# Consider the differential equation y''+by'+cy=f(t), where b,c are constants.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $y''+by'+cy=f(t)$, where $b$ and $c$ are constants. Suppose that $t^2 + 1 + e^t\cos(t)$, $t^2 + 1 + e^t\sin(t)$, and $t^2 + 1 + e^t\cos(t) + e^t \sin(t)$ are solutions.
(a) Determine two linearly independent solutions to the associated homogenous equation.
(b) Find b, c, f(t) that enables these solutions.

For (a) I figured that solving the homologous equation should give two linearly independent solutions, and I feel comfortable with that answer.  Part (b) is causing all sorts of trouble.  I don't know if I am approaching this the right way, but I tried plugging each of these solutions (and their derivatives and double derivatives) into the d.e. given.  I figured I could do this to solve for b and c by letting them all equal one another but this hasn't been an easy task.  Any idea if I am on the right track, and if not, how to solve this problem.  Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**.  If the differential equation with constant coefficients
$$y''+by'+cy=f(t)$$
has two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$, what can you figure out about $y_1-y_2$?

Comment: It has three solutions.

Comment: @Brandon what makes you think so?